# Styling Wicket datetimefield

Tags: css, wicket

I am using the DateTimeField component of Wicket, but I am struggling to apply any styling to it. The HTML snippet is this:

```
<span id="creationDate" wicket:id="creationDate" />
```

and the accompanying Java is:

```
add(new DateTimeField("creationDate", new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "creationDate")));
```

Which works, but produces this (which I have tidied up):

```
<span id="creationDate" wicket:id="creationDate">
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <input type="text" wicket:id="date" size="12" value="28/11/11" name="creationDate:date" id="date1f"/>
    <span class="yui-skin-sam">&nbsp;
        <span style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index: 99999;" id="date1fDp"></span>
        <img style="cursor: pointer; border: none;" id="date1fIcon" src="wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker/icon1-ver-1322148000242.gif" alt="" title=""/>
    </span>
    <input type="text" wicket:id="hours" size="2" value="14" name="creationDate:hours"/>
    <span wicket:id="hoursSeparator">&#160;:</span>
    <input type="text" wicket:id="minutes" size="2" value="17" name="creationDate:minutes"/>
</span>
```

What I am hoping to do is get the components separately, then either add `style` or `class` attributes to them. Any way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can just override the HTML, in this case by replacing `DateTimeField.html` in the `org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar` package. This then replaces the default HTML, and is where I added the class details.

Comment: True, that's also possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `public Component add(final Behavior... behaviors)` defined in the super class `Component`.

What you are looking for is the behavior `AttributeAppender` with which you can add CSS id/classes or every other attribute you want to append.

See the API: http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AttributeAppender.html

**UPDATE**

I just got a quick look at the source code of the `DateTimeField`. Unfortunately, you can't access the components separately.

I can think of two ways how you can style the components:

- You can put the whole `DateTimeField` inside a custom `div` and then, for example, accessing the textfields via cascading css selectors. (e.g. #myDiv input)
- or you create your own `DateTimeField` class with the existing source code and put your css id/classes there.

Comment: I realised my question wasn't written right, so I've edited the final paragraph. I'll look into what you say though ...